# Performance testing of dotnet core WebAPI

Tags: performance-testing, asp.net-core-webapi

I was wondering if there are any tools worth of trying to test dotnet core WebAPI performance during high load.

In the past I used `jMeter` of Apache, but configuring that alongside with TeamCity and dotnet core builds is a bit of pain.

I am looking for something that could deliver statistics, so automated run of tests can give me information if recent changes have or haven't decreased performance etc.

I also did a quick google, VisualStudio has something on board, but first of all it requires Enterprise edition of software, and I am not convinced if that tool is good enough.

Thank you

Comment: Hi there, we were in similar situation some time ago and in the end we've created our own library for it. It is continuous perf testing as a code and the main goal is exactly as you said: verifying that recent changes did not break performance of our apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet - it's a widely used and respected library.

If your goal is to test WebAPI you can create a HttpClient and use it for making calls to the API, wrap it in a benchmark and run it on TeamCity as a simple dotnet step.

The tool also can create reports in HTML which then can be added to TeamCity as a custom tab.

If it's not enough then you can extract performance metrics e.g. from [PlainExporter](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/configs/exporters.html) and integrate it with TeamCity built-in [Service Messages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/reporting-test-metadata.html) and create [Custom Charts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/custom-chart.html) from those stats so TeamCity will help you track performance trends.

You could even act on those measures and e.g. fail the build if there is a significant performance degradation.